# Sybase: Dump/load from a larger database to a smaller database

Tags: database, load, dump, sap-ase, shrink

How do I move a database (schema and data) into a smaller database? Sybase does not allow loading a dump into a smaller database than the original.

Sybase 12.5.3 ASE

Comment: Edited into a question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a similar problem and didn't realise that Sybase doesn't support the ability to "shrink" a database! So the only options I came up with are...

**Dump And Load**

Doing a full [dump and load](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-asarc/srv10024/sag/@Generic__BookTextView/21050;pt=20890). However if your target server does not have anough disk space you're out of luck! A real pain like my situation where the source database is only 5% used but the dump + load still requires the full 100% allocated database.

**Extract DDL and BCP Data**

Extract the DDL from the source database using [DDLGen](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.utility/html/utility/utility204.htm) or a tool like Embarcadero DBArtisan. Then use [BCP](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1502/html/utility/X14951.htm) to extract the data form the source database and import into the target database

Comment: Dump and Load: I wasn't able to load into a smaller database than the original. Maybe I missed an option?

Comment: You're correct Brian, you can't load into a smaller database. What my answer is saying is that "dump and load" was no good for me either because you have to load into a database of the same allocated size

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to put the dump in a database of the same size and then pass the schema and data to the smaller database.

Afterwords you can delete the first database (the biggest one).

---

With Sybase Central you can get the schema from the database quickly and afterwords you just need to bcp the data.

Comment: How do you pass the schema and data?

Comment: @Brian do you use Sybase Central?

Comment: No, is it worth a look? How does Sybase Central transfer databases? Via scripting? I've tried using RapidSQL and another tool to script a schema. The biggest hurdle I've found is they don't understand dependencies between stored procs. To make it tricker some stored procs depend on temporary tables created by other stored procs. Other problems: these tools don't script column defaults using user defined types correctly and we also have some data that violates FK constraints (yes bad). It all adds up to making it painful to transfer databases via scripts.